# Convert UTC Time to Local time in SQL Server 2014 When Using Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2008-r2

Problem: need to query large amount of time series data collected from different part of the world to generate different reports.

The time series table looks like this: LoggerId (int), Datetime (Datetime), Value (decimal).

The datetime are stored in UTC but they need to be converted into local times. In some cases data need to be aggregated using AVG, SUM to get things like daily/weekly/monthly average, total etc.

User can change the timezone of data used in their report at anytime. For example user A may decide to see logger #1's data in timezone A and user B may choose to see the same data in timezone B.

So far I could not find a good solution in SQL Server 2014 thanks to daylight savings which complicate thing dramatically. I know in SQL Server 2016 there is a new "At Time Zone" function which might be what I need but it is not available in 2014.

Any help will be appreciated.

Below are some sample data:

LoggerId, DatetimeUTC, Value

1, 2017-04-10 10:00:00, 10

1, 2017-04-10 11:00:00, 20

1, 2017-04-10 12:00:00, 30

1, 2017-04-10 13:00:00, 40

The expected result from a query that shows daily total of logger 1 in NZ time (UTC+12):

LoggerId, DatetimeLocal, Value

1, 2017-04-10, 30

1, 2017-04-11, 70

Comment: ,Post your sample data and expected output

Comment: I have simplified the question a little bit and added some sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to properly account for DST?

Comment: Yes. DST is the main reason I have this problem in the first place. I will update the question. Thanks

Comment: Since there is no suitable answer for this question after almost a year of waiting. I end up querying the raw data (without aggregate) into a List and converting the datetime in .NET using the TimezoneInfo class and then aggregate the data in .NET code. It is slower but overall performance is acceptable for my application. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t mind using unsafe CLR assemblies in your database then you can simply write your own .net CLR scalar function to perform the conversions for you. Below is a link to a GitHub project from Dicko2.0 that demonstrates how you can implement your own CLR:

https://github.com/HostedSolutions/SQLDates

The following OneDrive link contains the full install script for the above CLR project:

[SQLDatesFunc](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqjAzDSpWIyW5Q7FbKXjDMA2ENde)

Below is an example on the use of the assembly:

```
DECLARE @utcDateTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();

DECLARE @cstDateTime DATETIME;
DECLARE @estDateTime DATETIME;

SET @cstDateTime = [dbo].[ConvertToLocalTimeZone]('Central Standard Time', @utcDateTime);
SET @estDateTime = [dbo].[ConvertToLocalTimeZone]('Eastern Standard Time', @utcDateTime);

SELECT @cstDateTime AS CST, @estDateTime AS EST;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about the CLR approach as well. I haven't use it before so need to do some investigation. My main worry is its performance vs SQL and how its going to integrate into our current development environment.

Comment: @Robert no worries, with regards to performance the CLR option will outperform any custom UDFs created in SQL Server and will handle all the edge cases such as DST for you. My own test shows that calling the function on a million records only slows the query down by about a second. With regards to integration you should only need to run the script I have provided (it will create and install the assembly for you no compilation needed).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on below function which return DST, you can modify as per your requirement. you just pass utc datetime and offset. :

```
 Create FUNCTION [dbo].[UDTToLocalTime_Test](@UDT AS DATETIME,@offs as SMALLINT)  
 RETURNS DATETIME
 AS
BEGIN 
--====================================================
--Set the Timezone Offset (NOT During DST [Daylight Saving Time])
--====================================================
DECLARE @Offset AS SMALLINT
SET @Offset = @offs
--====================================================
--Figure out the Offset Datetime
--====================================================
DECLARE @LocalDate AS DATETIME
SET @LocalDate = DATEADD(hh, @Offset, @UDT)
--====================================================
--Figure out the DST Offset for the UDT Datetime
--====================================================
DECLARE @DaylightSavingOffset AS SMALLINT
DECLARE @Year as SMALLINT
DECLARE @DSTStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DSTEndDate AS DATETIME
--Get Year
SET @Year = YEAR(@LocalDate)
--Get First Possible DST StartDay
IF (@Year > 2006) SET @DSTStartDate = CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '-03-08 02:00:00'
ELSE SET @DSTStartDate = CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '-04-01 02:00:00'
--Get DST StartDate 
WHILE (DATENAME(dw, @DSTStartDate) <> 'sunday') SET @DSTStartDate = DATEADD(day, 1,@DSTStartDate)
--Get First Possible DST EndDate
IF (@Year > 2006) SET @DSTEndDate = CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '-11-01 02:00:00'
ELSE SET @DSTEndDate = CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '-10-25 02:00:00'
--Get DST EndDate 
WHILE (DATENAME(dw, @DSTEndDate) <> 'sunday') SET @DSTEndDate = DATEADD(day,1,@DSTEndDate)
--Get DaylightSavingOffset
SET @DaylightSavingOffset = CASE WHEN @LocalDate BETWEEN @DSTStartDate AND @DSTEndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
--====================================================
--Finally add the DST Offset 
--====================================================
RETURN DATEADD(hh, @DaylightSavingOffset, @LocalDate)
END
```

Just need to call like:

```
 select  [dbo].[UDTToLocalTime_Test](getutcdate(),+4) as DateSTim
```

Long time ago i found this solution and working fine for my scenario hopefully it will also help you.

Comment: This seems to implement two sets of DST rules based on some kind of switch-over but I'm not sure which countr(y/ies) this applies for. It sounds like the OP needs to work with multiple timezones and so, if you're going down this route you'd need to implement the rules for *all countries*, some of which it's impossible to future-proof for. Also, assumes that `DATENAME` is returning english, which is by no means a given.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a good way to maintain the timezone rules automatically for different countries? One problem with DST is they seems to change all the time. My other worry is the performance of the solution. Need to do some benchmark first.